# Dynamicly sorting a MYSQL Stored Procedure / Function

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL function called spGetVideosByLocation. Currently I call it like this:

```
CALL spGetVideosByLocation(location);
```

This basically calls a query similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE LocationId = location;
```

My question is, is there a way to define ORDER BY when I call the function? 
How do I get this:

```
CALL spGetVideosByLocation(location, "tableName", DESC);
```

To query this:

```
SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE LocationId = location ORDER BY tableName DESC;
```

Comment: i think you can not do a select * , choose what you want to select ,  its very simple what you need look on example - here http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you using?  Assuming you are using php, here is the code I would use:

```
function spGetVideosByLocation($locationid, $order, $orderby)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE LocationId = '$locationid' ORDER BY $order $orderby";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    //do whatever you need to to get results
}
```

Comment: I think he's referring to a [MySQL stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html).

Comment: oh my bad.  I hope this still helps

Comment: Blake, that would be too easy!! :-) I am using php / zend framework, but I want to call it from a MYSQL stored procedure/function. . .